# Pyodbc and Microsoft Access connecting Error

Tags: python

I've been trying to connect to Microsoft Access (64bit) with python 3.7.2 (64bit) via pyodbc. The code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\database accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from Map Generation')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Produces the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\NEA\ACCESS TESTING.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\database accdb;')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I've checked some posts, and most suggest to download the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, which I also tried. As this post suggests https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access to check if Microsoft Access driver is available in python environment the following code can be run:

```
import pyodbc
[x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]
```

For me this still produces nothing. Is there something I need to do to link the Microsoft Access Driver to my python environment?

Comment: Did you find out a solution to this?